# PBS: Can a large-memory serial job make use of memory from more than one node?

Tags: hpc, pbs

I am a new user to high-performance computing, I am trying to run a serial job that requires around 80GB memory in total. However the total memory available for one node is only 12GB for our cluster (Our lab's cluster is a little old). I read through some guides online and to my understanding, only MPI jobs can make use of memory from more than one node? Is it true? Any ideas on how to solve my particular problem? Thank you guys very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is some sort of shared memory abstraction for distributed systems. Unfortunately clusters or any other HPC system doesn't work like that and you need to utilize inter-node communication (message passing) to access more memory.  MPI is the de-facto standard for distributed processing and you won't be able to accomplish weak-scaling beyond a node's memory limits without making edits to the code.

Answer (score -1):

I have never heard MPI would be able to run code that would require more memory than on a single node (unless the application was specifically designed to share memory between nodes). ElasticOS works on that, though: http://synergy.cs.vt.edu/2015-nsf-xps-workshop/reports/Richard_Han_45-Conference_Presentation_ElasticOS_XPS_2015.2.pdf